# Let $f(x)=o(i(x))$. If $i$ is continuous at $p$, and $o$ is continuous $i(p)$, then $f$ is continuous at $p$. Is my proof for this statement correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, solution-verification, continuity

I've been trying to prove that if some function $i$ is continuous at a point $p$, and another function $o$ is continuous at $i(p)$, then these two statements imply that some other function $f$ is also continuous at $p$, where we define $f(x)=o(i(x))$.

I believe I've come up with a proof for this statement, but due to my lack of familiarity with $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs, I wonder if I've made a big mistake somewhere here that I can't recognise, and so I am hoping that someone can confirm whether or not the following proof is acceptable:

Choose some $\epsilon>0$.

Then, since $\lim_{i(x)\to i(p)}[o(i(x))]=o(i(p))$, we know that a $\delta>0$, which we call $\delta_{o}$, exists, such that: $|i(p)-i(x)|<\delta_{o}\implies |o(i(p))-o(i(x))|<\epsilon$.

And since $\lim_{x\to p}i(x)=i(p)$, we know that a $\delta>0$, which we call $\delta_{i}$, exists, such that: $|p-x|<\delta_{i} \implies |i(p)-i(x)|<\delta_{o}$.

Recall that, by definition, $f(x)=o(i(x))$ and $f(p)=o(i(p))$.

So we see that, $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta_{i}>0$, such that $|p-x|<\delta_{i}\implies |f(p)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, which, by definition, implies continuity of $f$ at $p$. $\square$

EDIT:

I assume that $i$ is continuous at $p$, and that $o$ is continuous at $i(p)$, and then try to show that these two assumptions imply that $f$ is continuous at $p$.

Specifically, my problem is in understanding whether or not the approach I've taken here is valid: given some $\epsilon>0$, we use the assumption that $o$ is continuous at $i(p)$ to construct a $\delta_{o}$, then use this $\delta_{o}$ as a kind of "arbitrary epsilon" we demand $i(x)$'s value be strictly within $i(p)$ of, in some neighbourhood of $p$. Then we show that, assuming $i$ is continuous at $p$, such a neighbourhood exists, and its radius is given by $\delta_{i}$.

Then we state that since a $\delta_{i}$ exists for any given $\epsilon>0$, this implies that for any $\epsilon$ we demand $f(x)$ be strictly within $f(p)$ of, there exists a neighbourhood of $x$-values around (and at) $p$, with radius given by $\delta_{i}$, for which all values of $f$ over that neighbourhood satisfy the $\epsilon$ demand. And this means that $f$ is continuous at $p$.

Is this reasoning sound?

The part of the proof I am most in doubt of is the constructing of a $\delta$, namely $\delta_{o}$, that we then use in the type of way we commonly use epsilons; as a kind of demand on how close $i(x)$ must come to $i(p)$ as $x\to p$. I haven't seen this used before (I haven't seen many $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs in general), and so this is the part I am most worried about the validity of.

Comment: Please don't use us as automatic proof-checkers. Look at the [description of the solution-verification tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification). *"Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so."*

Comment: Start your proof by stating what you assume.  Your first "since" seems to state something you do not yet know?  Also state your setting: functions on $\mathbb R$, metric space, topological space, etc.?

Comment: @GEdgar On real numbers, and I assume that $i$ is continuous at $p$ and that $o$ is continuous at $i(p)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I've edited my post, is this sufficient explanation? I'm not sure how to be more specific.

Comment: Your efforts are commendable, but they are rewording your proof, instead of pointing "precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so".

Comment: @AnneBauval OK, I've edited again pointing out the part I am most doubtful of, is this fine?

Comment: You did your best, and your proof was anyway excellent (imo).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much. Also, if you want to turn your confirmation into an answer I will accept it; I think this question will stay open otherwise.

Comment: To directly address your concern: by the continuity of $i$, you already know $$\forall\epsilon_i > 0,\exists\delta_i > 0,\forall x, |x - p| < \delta_i \implies |i(x) -  i(p)| < \epsilon_i$$ This holds for any value chosen for $\epsilon_i$. In particular, it still holds when the value of $\epsilon_i$ is $\delta_o$. You are just taking advantage of that fact.